# How does reinitailization works with local and top-level variable in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, global-variables, local-variables

```
bool isAdult = false;
 isAdult=!isAdult;//error 
void main(List<String> args) {
  //If-statements
  isAdult=!isAdult; //no error
  int age = 21;
  if (age >= 21) {
    print('Adult 21');
  } else if (age >= 18) {
    print('adult');
  } else {
    print('child');
  }

  if (isAdult && age!=18) {
    print('Adult 21');
  } else if (age >= 18) {
    print('adult');
  } else {
    print('child');
  }
}
```

why when reassigned outside gives me error but when reassigned inside main function doesn't ?

**It would be helpful if someone could explain me how top-level variables are different in terms of reassignment as compared to local variables in dart?**

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, the top-level variable it should not be in a code block {}.

So when assigning, Dart will understand that you are declaring another variable, but there are 2 problems: duplicate names and incorrect syntax.

If written in a specific block, Dart will understand that the variable has been defined and the assignment is accepted.

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  bool isAdult = false;
  isAdult=!isAdult;
}
```

Hope useful to you! xD